# How to solve "Autoloading failed to define function sml-mode"?

Tags: debugging

I have just install a version of emacs (GNU Emacs 24.5.1 i686-pc-mingw32) on a Windows 8 Machine. On trying to open an example SML file (Standard ML Language). An error occurred:

> File mode specification error: (error "Autoloading failed to define function sml-mode")

On deeper inspection the debugger shows this:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Autoloading failed to define function sml-mode") 
>     sml-mode() 
>     set-auto-mode-0(sml-mode nil) 
>     set-auto-mode()
>     normal-mode(t) 
>     after-find-file(nil t) 
>     find-file-noselect-1(# "g:/example00.sml" nil nil "g:/example00.sml" ((512 4 . 8192) (48259 . 42323))) 
>  
>     find-file-noselect("g:/example00.sml" nil nil nil)
>     find-file("g:/example00.sml") 
>     find-file-existing("g:/example00.sml") 
>     menu-find-file-existing() 
>     call-interactively(menu-find-file-existing nil nil) 
>     command-execute(menu-find-file-existing)

How can I resolve this error?

Edit : I installed sml-mode via `list-packages`.

Comment: Is the directory that contains the library that defines `sml-mode` in your `load-path`? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: @Drew How do I do that? (To be honest, I am very new to using emacs.)

Comment: See the Emacs manual, node [Lisp Libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html). In a nutshell, you use `(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/your/directory/")` and then you use `(require 'the-library)`.

Comment: If you installed the library using the package interface then be sure to use `(package-initialize)`. In that case, you should not need to fiddle with `load-path` and `require`.

Comment: @Drew And how do I `(package-initialize)`?

Comment: Put that in your init file. Start by reading about your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem of conflicting libraries in `load-path`. 
I think you should inspect your `load-path` to see if you have `sml-mode` directory in it twice. The first directory probably doesn't contain a definition for `sml-mode` and hence Emacs fails to load it from there.

You can do `M-x list-load-path-shadows` to see if some `sml-mode` like file is shadowing the original file with the right definitions.